# Android Intent not opeining in Android Chrome recent version 110

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

I am trying to open to UPI payment link in the chrome browser on mobile devices but it's failing, I cannot figure out the exact reason.

failures observed in

> chrome:110, android 12, nokia device

passed in

> chrome:110, android 11, one plus device,

> safari: 16, ios 16,

> firefox

[sample UPI links](https://codepen.io/ashish-ashish-the-sasster/pen/dyqyNpW)

```
<a target="_self" href="upi://pay?pa=Naukri.payu@indus&pn=Info Edge India Limited&tr=16796361409&am=1.00">Link1</a>

<a target="_self" href="upi://pay? pa=jeevansathi1.payu@hdfcbank&pn=Info Edge India Limited&tr=16796449075&am=1.00">Link2</a>

<a target="_self" href="upi://pay?tr=202101345671229366&tid=121313202101345671229366&pa=juspay@axisbank&mc=1234&pn= Merchant%20Inc&am=1.00&cu=INR&tn=Pay%20for%20merchant">Link3</a>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have made some slight mistakes in this URL,
First of all, the `&` character in this URL should be escaped i.e. `&amp;`
Also, you have to enter the currency as INR i.e. `cu=INR`

The complete working link can be given as:

```
<a href="upi://pay?pa=Naukri.payu@indus&amp;pn=Info Edge India Limited&amp;tr=16796361409&amp;am=1.00&amp;cu=INR">Pay Now !</a>
```

The more general URL is something like-

```
upi://pay?pa=UPI_ID&amp;pn=NAME_OF_MERCHANT&amp;tr=TRANSACTION_ID&amp;am=AMOUNT&amp;cu=INR
```

Small Note: Adding any spaces in this URL is completely fine :). The spaces are automatically escaped to the `%20` ASCII code.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but unfortunately it doesn't work in the desired browser(refer my question again plz),

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot have your Nokia device but, I have Google Pixel 6a, having Android 12 with Chrome 110. It works as expected.